# Create a bash alias where the output is a concatenation without a space

Tags: bash, alias

The question is really simple. I want to create an alias, e.g.`alias short="echo a$1"`. When I run `short k` I get the output `a k`, but what I actually want is `ak`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I suggest to use a function. See: `help function`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
alias short="echo a$1b"

>> ab k
```

Its not working like you think it is. The $1 is getting resolved before the set to alias is finished  is finished, so therefore:

```
alias -p 
>> alias short='echo ab'
```

But bigger picture you are confusing an `alias` which is a dumb replacement of one token with another and a `function` which is meant to take parameters in the fashion you are trying to do here. What you probably are after is

```
function short(){ echo "a$1"; } 

short k 
>> ak
```

N.B. If you have already defined alias, don't forget to `unalias` it because the alias with get run before the function.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Really helpful!